# Is my question about looking for code examples on topic for SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am struggling to find any resources to help me write a plugin for the [Remote Desktop Gateway API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee672231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I asked the question [Where to find example code for the RD Gateway API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472611/where-to-find-example-code-for-the-rd-gateway-api) but it is not getting a lot of views and I think the two main reasons is SO is not the best site to post the question and the title smells of "Show me teh codez". For the first issue, I do not know where to post the question instead of SO.

- Super User - Not really a general software question
- Server Fault - Would be a correct place if I needed help administrating the normal interface, but I don't think programming questions fit here.
- CS Theory - Not really a "research-level question"
- Programmers - Maybe, best candidate beside SO, but this is not a "conceptual question"
- Code Review - If I had code for other people to look at, I did search there for some examples but no results.
- Web Applications - It may be using IIS but I really don't think RD Gateway is a "Web App"

Should I leave my question on SO or should it go on some other site? Or is it not appropriate for the Stack Exchange network at all?

For the second reason, any recommendations on a better title for my SO question so it does not look like someone begging for the work to be done for them would be appreciated too.

Comment: Ummm you asked it 40 minutes ago!  Give it time....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this category of question does walk a fine line on Stack Overflow (I don't know anything about the other sites, so I won't comment on them).

On the one hand, it *does* seem sort of like a "plz show me teh codez" question, or at best, one where "every answer is equally valid" (which is [a no-no](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)). I can imagine this type of question getting closed as either "not a real question", or "not constructive".

But on the other hand, your question is well-written, very likely to be useful to other people in the future, and is a "practical, answerable [question] based on actual problems that you face". It's neither hypothetical nor inviting of a discussion. It requires specific knowledge of an API.

So I think *your* question is fine. But that shouldn't be taken to imply that *all* such questions of this nature are necessarily valid and won't be closed for any number of reasons. Things like this have to be judged on a case-by-case basis, which is why it takes 5 community members to agree in order to get a question closed, and why 5 other community members can agree to re-open a closed question.

For me, **a question that is coherent, well-written, and shows evidence of effort on the part of the asker will go a *long* way towards persuading me not to click that "close" button**—something that I find myself doing rather frequently on SO now. In fact, as in this case, it often persuades me to go so far as clicking the up arrow.

> For the second reason, any recommendations on a better title for my SO question so it does not look like someone begging for the work to be done for them would be appreciated too.

I think the title is just fine: it succinctly and accurately conveys the question you're asking, which is really all that a title should strive to do. Anyone reading the question should be perfectly capable of figuring out that you're not simply asking for someone to do your work for you.

Comment: Looks like a question asking for [rotting links](http://idontexistanymorewhyareyoucomingherewhatiswrongwithyou.com).

Comment: Not if the sample code is added to the answer... Link-only answers have never really been acceptable, I don't know how that's unique to this particular question.

Comment: *"Can anyone a link to"* was the first hint.  Any question asking for "any kind of tutorial" is a big red flag.  Also, he wants to know how to use an API.  That's verging on "not a real question" territory, as the answer is going to tend to be complex and long...